# ERROR: 'Slice not a member' when implementing Asynchronous-iterators in Phantom-DSL

Tags: scala, phantom-dsl

I am trying to follow the Asynchronous iterators example from the [wiki](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Asynchronous-iterators)

Am getting the following error:

> value slice is not a member of play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator

Any input into what the issue is greatly appreciated.

---

This is so that I can paginate results from a large collection

---

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.websudos" %% "phantom-dsl" % 1.22.0,
  "com.websudos" %% "phantom-reactivestreams" % 1.22.0 
)
```

---

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.{ResultSet, Row}
import com.websudos.phantom.CassandraTable
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._
import com.websudos.phantom.iteratee.Iteratee
import org.dyne.danielsan.openblockchain.data.entity.Block

import scala.concurrent.Future
import com.websudos.phantom.reactivestreams._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

sealed class BlocksModel extends CassandraTable[BlocksModel, Block] {

  override def fromRow(row: Row): Block = {
    Block(
      hash(row),
      height(row)
}

  object hash extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]

  object height extends IntColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Int] with Descending

  object order_id extends LongColumn(this) with ClusteringOrder[Long] with Descending

abstract class ConcreteBlocksModel extends BlocksModel with RootConnector {

  override val tableName = "blocks"

  def getBlocks(start: Int, limit: Int): Future[Set[Block]] = {
    select.fetchEnumerator.slice(start, limit).collect
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly wrong syntax, when you want to use methods on enumerator here's what you need:

```
abstract class ConcreteBlocksModel extends BlocksModel with RootConnector {

  override val tableName = "blocks"

  def getBlocks(start: Int, limit: Int): Future[Iterator[Block]] = {
    select.fetchEnumerator run Iterator.slice(start, limit)
  }
}
```

If you want to paginate your records, there's a different way to do that in Cassandra with automated pagination though.

```
def getPage(limit: Int, paging: Option[PagingState] = None): Future[ListResult[JodaRow]] = {
  select.limit(limit).fetchRecord(paging)
}
```

And basically you need to provide a paging state for the next query to run. The `Future` now being returned will have a `ListResult` item inside of it, which means you get 2 methods:

```
def records: List[R] // the list of records from the db, just like fetch()
def pagingState: PagingState // the state you care about.
```

Basically `pagingState` has a `toString` method which will give you back a token you will need to store on the client side. When the user wants to get "the next page", you need to provide the `pagingState` string from the previous page, think of the paging state as a pointer to a particular location in the Cassandra table, so that way Cassandra knows how to "jump" or "skip pages".

So your next API call, assuming you start from page 0, should include a `pagingState` as a string.

You can then you `PagingState.fromString(pagingState)` and pass the result of this to get the "next page".

I will add an example of this in phantom, but this should basically solve your current problem.

Comment: where does ListResult resides? I am using 1.22.0 version. Also fetchRecord method is not found.

Comment: @carpenter I think you need a more recent version for `ListRecord` to exist, it should be on the default `import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._`